# I need to output colored text

Tags: vb.net, text, colors

Okay, so what I want to do is directly output formatted RTF text to a Rich Text Box control in VB.NET. I don't want to find the text, select it and color it as it is not practical for what I'm doing. I've tried outputting RTF code but that isn't working either. Can I actually do this or will I have to write a dll?

Comment: Yes, this is fully supported.  You will have to read the rather large RTF specification to learn how to format the Rtf property string correctly.  Most programmers use a machine to get that right.  And use, you guessed it, the RichTextBox class to make the conversion.  Consider using HTML instead, WebBrowser.DocumentText to display it.

Comment: Hans, you have solved my problem. I used the web browser instead. Can you post this as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all good! I found a different way of approaching my problem.